# Comma separating numbers without advance knowledge of number of digits in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres 9.5:

```
select to_char(111, 'FM9,999'); -- gives 111
select to_char(1111, 'FM9,999'); -- gives 1,111
select to_char(11111, 'FM9,999'); -- gives #,### !!!
```

How can I format my numbers with commas without advance knowledge/assumption of maximum number of possible digits preferably by using built-in stuff like above?

Comment: for reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add another digit or the maximum possible value:

```
select to_char(11111, 'FM9,999,999');
```

Comment: i need a solution without advance knowledge/assumption of maximum number of possible digits

Comment: This will work fine, just make your format big enough for largest possible value that can be stored in DB. Max int value is 2 billion, so "FM9,999,999,999" will display them all.

Comment: Well if you use `sum(some_column)` then you can get over that 2 billion limit quite easily.

Comment: i guess the solution is always use the largest possible value "FM9,999,999,999"

Answer (score 2):

Another work around is to convert to money, then to varchar and replace the $ symbol

```
Select replace(round(sum(quantity), 2)::money::varchar, '$', '') as Total from...
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @rudy_dark_1's answer, I'm using

```sql
SELECT
  rtrim(ltrim(
    -------------------------
    -- Value / Calculation here
    11111.15
    -------------------------
  ::money::varchar, '$'), '.00') AS column_name_here
;
```

I include `AS column_name_here`, because `replace`/`ltrim`/`rtrim`, will change the outputted "column name".

^I particularly like this, because I'm using non-decimal values(typically getting info on row query counts for instance).

`rtrim` and `ltrim` are a slight "enhancement", because there's one less argument that has to go to them.

If you are working with a decimal/float, it becomes even simpler (no `rtrim`):

```sql
SELECT
  ltrim(
    -------------------------
    -- Value / Calculation here
    11111.15
    -------------------------
  ::money::varchar, '$') AS column_name_here
;
```