# How to show comma separated numbers in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
|     size      |
|---------------|
| 2880129015916 |
|          2560 |
|             0 |
|      91570752 |
|          8192 |
|      21037156 |
```

and I want to display the values as comma separated, for example, 2880129015916 will be shown as  2,880,129,015,916.

I already saw an elegant solution on SO, [Comma separating numbers without advance knowledge of number of digits in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370562/comma-separating-numbers-without-advance-knowledge-of-number-of-digits-in-postgr)

However when I apply this to the table I get

```
|     size      |         x         |
|---------------|-------------------|
| 2880129015916 | 2,880,129,015,916 |
|          2560 | 2,56              |
|             0 |                   |
|      91570752 | 91,570,752        |
|          8192 | 8,192             |
|      21037156 | 21,037,156        |
```

My query was

```
 SELECT v99.size,
    rtrim(ltrim(v99.size::money::character varying::text, '$'::text), '.00'::text) AS x
   FROM v99;
```

Any ideas why 2560 was shown as 2,56 and 0 was shown as ''?
Thanks.

Comment: Better to do this in your application/presentation layer, not in your SQL. You could use to_char() if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I agree. I don't have an application for this - I am just curious why this 'elegant' solution does not seem to work in some cases.

Comment: Why not `G999G999G999G999G999`? Seems to work for all your tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
select size, to_char(size,'FM99,999,999,999,999,999,999') from myTable;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FSET1FyR)

EDIT: BTW, why your trick is faulty and not working?

```
rtrim(ltrim(v99.size::money::character varying::text, '$'::text), '.00'::text)
```

You are converting size to money, which makes it like:

| v |
| --- |
| $2,880,129,015,916.00 |
| $2,560.00 |

Then you convert it to character varying and then to text (which is redundant and the same thing, done twice).

Then you left trim the characters '$' (which is already text and casting is unnecessary). They become like:

| v |
| --- |
| 2,880,129,015,916.00 |
| 2,560.00 |

Then you do a right trim this time to "trim characters" '.00' meaning you are trimming all '0' and '.' characters from right leaving:

| v |
| --- |
| 2,880,129,015,916 |
| 2,56 |

Hope this makes it clear why it was not working. Simply use the formatting I showed.

Answer (score 0):

data

```
create table mytable (size numeric(20,0));
insert into mytable 
(size) values 
(2880129015916),
(2560),
(0),
(91570752),
(8192),
(21037156);
```

use following query

```
select  size,replace(replace(round(sum(size), 0)::money::varchar, '$', ''),'.00','') 
from mytable 
group by size
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9u374nd8)

Answer (score 0):

To do it client-side with `psql` (which seems to be your client in use):

```
\pset numericlocale on
```